# How do I wrap a C++ class with Cython?

Tags: c++, python, python-2.7, cython

I have a C++ class.  It's made up of one .ccp file and one .h file.  It compiles (I can write a main method that uses it successfully in c++).  How do I wrap this class with Cython to make it available in Python?

I've read the docs and don't follow.  They talk about generating the cpp file.  When I've tried to follow the docs, my already existing cpp gets blown away...

What am I meant to put in the pyx file?  I've been told the class definition but how much of it?  Just the public methods?

Do I need a .pxd file?  I don't understand when this file is or isn't required.

I've tried asking these question in the #python IRC channel and can't get an answer.

Comment: If your question has been answered, please mark this question as answered. Otherwise please specify your question once more.

Comment: @NiklasR Your answer covered some of my areas of confusion but didn't get me all the way.  I've given you a vote up but intended to write a full answer of the other bits I worked out when I have some time to spare.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So after lots of poking, trial and error, screaming and tearing my hair out, I finally got this to work.  First though, I had to re-write my C++ into C, which for me really just involved converting all my `std::string` variables to `char*` and keeping track of some lengths.

Once done I had my .h and .c files.  I wanted to make a single function from the C code available in Python.  It turns out that Cython can compile your C files into the extension for you and link any libraries all in one go, so starting with my setup.py, it ended up looking like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules=[
  Extension("myext",
    ["myext.pyx", "../stuff.c"],
    libraries=["ssl", "crypto"]
  )
]

setup(
  name = "myext",
  cmdclass = {"build_ext": build_ext},
  ext_modules = ext_modules
)
```

As you can see, the second argument to the Extension simply lists all the files that need to be compiled, Cython works out how to compile them depending on their file extension as far as I can tell.  The libraries array tells the Cython compiler what needs to be linked in (in this case I was wrapping some crypto stuff that I couldn't seem to mimick directly through existing Python libs).

To actually make my C function available in the .pyx file, you write a small wrapper in the .pxd.  My myext.pxd looked as below:

```
cdef extern from "../stuff.h":
    char* myfunc(char* arg1, char* arg2, char* arg3)
```

In the .pyx you then use the cimport declaration to import this function, which is then available for use as if it were any other Python function:

```
cimport myext

def my_python_func(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    result = myext.myfunc(arg1, arg2, arg3)
    return result
```

When you build this (on Mac at least) you get a .so that you can import in python and run the functions from the .pyx.  There may be better, more correct way to get this all working but that comes from experience and this was a first encounter that I managed to work out.  I'd be very interested on pointers where I may have gone wrong.

**Update:**

After further use of Cython, I found it was super simple to integrate it with C++ too, once you know what you're doing.  Making C++'s `string` available is as simple as `from libcpp.string cimport string` in your pyx/pyd.  Declaring the C++ class is similarly easy as:

```
cdef extern from "MyCPPClass.h":
    cdef cppclass MyCPPClass:
        int foo;
        string bar;
```

Sure you have to basically redeclare the .h definition of your class in a Pythonic format, but that's a small price to pay for getting access to your already written C++ functions.

Comment: Please help me out! I would really like to use Python 3.3 with Cython & C++, would you maybe have some example files? I have the latest Cython and Python installed.

Comment: I don't have any example files for Python 3, however, make sure you're setting the compiler flags correctly http://wiki.cython.org/FAQ#WhatPythonversionsdoesCythonsupport.3F

Ask a question here on SO with more specific problems you're encountering. If you link it here in the comments I can take a look.

Comment: Not sure if this will be particularly helpful as an example, but I wrote [this Python 3.3 wrapper for a C++ library](https://github.com/wmayner/pyemd).

Comment: FYI, std::string is now supported as well as char*

Answer (score 22):

Even Cython is generally for use with *C*, it can generate *C++* code, too. When compiling, you add the `--cplus` flag.

Now, creating a wrapper for the class is simple and not much different from wrapping a structure. It mainly differs from declaring the `extern`, but that's not much difference at all.

Suppose you have a class `MyCppClass` in `mycppclass.h`.

```
cdef extern from "mycppclass.h":
    cppclass MyCppClass:
        int some_var

        MyCppClass(int, char*)
        void doStuff(void*)
        char* getStuff(int)

cdef class MyClass:

    # the public-modifier will make the attribute public for cython,
    # not for python. Maybe you need to access the internal C++ object from
    # outside of the class. If not, you better declare it as private by just
    # leaving out the `private` modifier.
    # ---- EDIT ------
    # Sorry, this statement is wrong. The `private` modifier would make it available to Python,
    # so the following line would cause an error es the Pointer to MyCppClass
    # couldn't be converted to a Python object.
    #>> cdef public MyCppClass* cobj
    # correct is:
    cdef MyCppClass* obj

    def __init__(self, int some_var, char* some_string):
        self.cobj = new MyCppClass(some_var, some_string)
        if self.cobj == NULL:
            raise MemoryError('Not enough memory.')

    def __del__(self):
        del self.cobj

    property some_var:
        def __get__(self):
            return self.cobj.some_var
        def __set__(self, int var):
            self.cobj.some_var = var
```

Note that the `new` keyword is only available when the `--cplus` flag is set, otherwise use `malloc` from `<stdlib.h>` by externing it.

Also note that you don't need to dereference the pointer (`->`) to call the method. Cython tracks the object's type and applies what fits.

.pxd files are for seperating declarations from implementation, or to avoid namespace colliding. Imagine you'd like to name you Python-wrapper like the C++ class. Simply put in your .pxd file the `extern` declarations and `cimport` the pxd file in the .pyx.

```
cimport my_pxd
cdef my_pxd.SomeExternedType obj
```

Note that you can not write implementations in a .pxd file.

Comment: So my C++ uses functionality from OpenSSL.  Are those functions what I need to declare in my pxd?

Comment: Also, I can convert the C++ to C, but that hasn't really helped me get any further with the problem...

Comment: Any functions you want to use in Cython need to be declared within Cythons scope. It can be declared in either your `.pyx` or `.pxd` file, depends on the projects complexity to keep it tidy and wether you want to name Python functions exactly like their C++ originals.

Comment: `cdef MyCppClass* obj` looks like a `static member` in C++. What is the point of having that?

Answer (score 3):

Cython is mainly for C development, to integrate C++ with Python I would recommend [**Boost.Python**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/python/doc/). Their excellent documentation should get you started pretty quickly.

Comment: In addition to Boost.Python, Shinboken (from the PySide project), and SIP (From the PyQT project) and I believe SWIG can also wrap C++ objects. You could in theory wrap C++ code with Cython, but you'd have to use mangled names and do a lot of stuff by hand - I wouldn't recommend it myself.

Comment: As I have *very* high regards for Boost and the quality of many of its libraries, it is usually my first choice when given a list of options. As for the options you presented: PySide is relatively new and as far as I'm concerned, unproven. SIP is under a GPL license which may deter some people. I've had some unpleasant experience with SWIG, so I can't recommend it myself. As always, YMMV, but in my opinion you can hardly go wrong with Boost.

Comment: @spatz I'm sorry but I can't agree on excellent documentation for Boost.Python, or even Boost in general.  I've found their documentation just plain misleading or missing entirely in the past.  I was working with their networking/socket libraries a couple of months ago and it was a massive amount of trial and error.

Comment: @Endophage, I didn't say all of Boost's documentation was good, I was merely referring to the Boost.Python documentation. While other Boost libraries often lack in documentation (but they make up for it in popularity and amount of help you can get online), I find Boost.Python's to be rather good.

Comment: @spatz well I'll have anther look but I was trying to work with Boost.Python about 6 months ago on something else and could even get the hello world example to compile.  I'm on a Mac FYI so sometimes the docs don't quite line up...

Comment: @spatz - I can appreciate your feelings on Boost. I was just offering up some alternatives. For the record, I'm a fan of PySide's Shinboken but even though Boost::Python and Shinboken ultimately provide the same type of service - they approach it in different ways. The main advantage of PySide is that it can generate wrappers automatically where as with Boost::Python you have to write them by hand as far as I've seen. GCC-XML / et all haven't been updated in quite a while.. If I were building something from the ground up tho - Boost::Python no question.

Comment: I just downloaded boost and tried to build bjam... `-bash: ./bootstrap.sh: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

Comment: I had the same problem in Mac and finally got it running(bjam) with the packet boost-build from homebrew.

Comment: @synthesizerpatel: wrapping C++ code in Python by hand is much easier if you use `extern C` and maybe a thin C wrapper around the C++ code.

Answer (score 2):

The answers above have more or less answered the OP's question.

But its now passing the mid of 2020 and I'd thought to put a contribution (in the form of resource summary) here for those who want to explore Python-C++ bindings via python packages that can be 'pip installed' (or in the PyPI).

I'd reckon for calling C++ from Python / wrapping over third party libs , one can look at cppyy. Its a relatively young project but it certainly looks promising and backed with a modern compiler. See the link below:
https://cppyy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Also, there's always pybind11 ....
https://github.com/pybind/pybind11

Cython also supports C++ natively (for most of the C++ languages) ; for more information see https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html